# How to see an xml object in firefox console

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, firefox

```
jQuery.get("oberonmetadata.xml", function(metadata){
    console.log(metadata);
});
```

This shows me [column,column,.... (as shown in pic below)] in console and when I click on it, it exands its whole object tree structure...

Whereas all I want to see is metadata.xml file in console.  This works flawlessly in chrome but in IE-9 and mozilla I am unable to do it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It is working as intended, you are seeing the xml document. To ensure that it gets parsed properly in all browsers, add `,"xml")` to the end after `}`

Comment: This might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery

Comment: Kevin... How can I see the XML in console. Its showing me the whole object. In chrome I see the xml. I have edited my question and have put an image too.

Comment: @andy - no i am not looking to convert to string. I need to see xml (which will be formatted and easy to read) in console itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(metadata.xml);`

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to log the response to console, utilize the 3rd parameter passed to the success callback and examine its responseText property which contains a string representation of the document returned.

```
$.get("oberonmetadata.xml", function(data, status, response){
    console.log(response.responseText);
});
```

This works for me in all browser environments.