# Use jquery to load xml file, edit it, then save to server again with php

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I want to be able to load an xml file from my server. Edit a node in the xml with jQuery and then save this change with the rest of the xml file back to the server using php. Anyone know how to do this? I have code that changes the xml node and can see this in my console. But cannot get the code back to my server.

Thanks!

```
<?php
$xml = $_POST['xml'];
$file = fopen("data.xml","w");
fwrite($file, $xml);
fclose($file);
?> 

$.post('saveXml.php', { xml: $(data)}, function(data){alert('data loaded');});
```

if I console.log(data) I get #document and all the xml nodes. I also get the data.xml file on my server but it's blank.

Comment: show us the code you are using that isn't working

Comment: Added code...thianks @charlietfl

Comment: var_dump your $xml and see if you are getting complete xml at php end, also check your webpages view source, sometimes xml doesn't appear on webpage

Comment: how do I var_dump my $xml - like this var_dump($xml) - also how do I check this? @Pankaj Khairnar

Comment: I get this in my console.log - don't know if it helps
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: yes write like this in you php file : $xml = $_POST['xml']; var_dump($xml);

Comment: My comment above is what I get so dont even know if its going to the server any more @Pankaj Khairnar

Comment: these two must be your different files, one for php one for normal xml and you call your php file from ajax, is it the same structure you are have, also can you give any online link so that I can check your code

Comment: I think you are confuse between $(data) & data no ? try `{xml : data} `

Comment: I have a little test site here - blinqcreative.co.uk/xml @Pankaj Khairnar

Comment: ok...got the server to create the new file but it's empty. demo in link above. @Pankaj Khairnar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have never done this before but found some information here:  [Convert xml to string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery)
I have tested the following which will modify the original xml and send back to server as a string received by `$_POST['xml']`

```
$(function() {
    $.get('test.xml', function(xml) {
        var $xml = $(xml)
         /* change all the author names in original xml*/
        $xml.find('author').each(function() {
            $(this).text('New Author Name');

        })

        var xmlString=jQ_xmlDocToString($xml)

            /* send modified  xml string to server*/    
        $.post('updatexml.php', {xml:xmlString },function (response){             
             console.log(response)
             /* using text dataType to avoid serializing xml returned from `echo $_post['xml'];` in php*/
        }'text')
    }, 'xml')
});

function jQ_xmlDocToString($xml) {
    /* unwrap xml document from jQuery*/
    var doc = $xml[0];
    var string;
    /* for IE*/
    if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        string = doc.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else {
        string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc);
    }
    return string;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/54L5g/

Comment: Does this mean I have to change my xml data to a string before I send it back to the server? @charlietfl

Comment: Could you please have a look at my demo at blinqcreative.co.uk/xml and let me know what I'm missing - my php script is in the example above. Thanks @charlietfl

Comment: you need to convert the xml doc to string as I have in `jQ_xmlDocToString`. You can see in demo that the code I provided works, so try using it

Comment: Ok so used your code and it seems to load and no errors...but...no xml in the new file. Is my php script correct? @charlietfl

Comment: error in console needs to be fixed. If you are going to change the xml it needs to be in `$( data)` so my function expects a jQuery object passed in, not the original doc

Comment: Amazing...I now have xml in a new file! Thanks so much for you patience and help. First time dealing with xml and php - but you've really helped me.