# Read, Update XML column client side using Breeze JS

Tags: xml-serialization, client-side, breeze

Breeze render xml column (SQL xml data column) as it is (not converted to object as Breeze used to).
For example, bellow is data received client-side from Breeze :

```
<employee><firstname>Martin</firstname><lastname>MALONGA</lastname><age>74</age></employee>
```

1. How to access this xml element at client-side using Breeze? are they functions like xquery inside breeze platform?
2. How to update xml element client side and hope Breeze will transfer it to server?

*For the 1st question I'd tried **parser.parseFromString** and get something but with a painful gymnastic labor; hope someone will pull out a better approch.*

Comment: Are you asking how do you use breeze with an XML-based API? I don't believe Breeze supports XML responses, but I'd imagine you could hack together something by intercepting the HTTP response and converting it to JSON. Can you try to make your question a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the XML using jquery selectors.

**Access element**

```
var employee = $(returnedBreezeObservable());
var firstname = employee.children('firstname').text();
```

**Change element**

NOTE: the xmlToString function was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery).

```
function xmlToString(xmlData) { 
    var xmlString;
    //IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else{
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }
    return xmlString;
}   

var employee = $(returnedBreezeObservable());
employee.children('firstname').text('John');
employee.children('lastname').text('Doe');
returnedBreezeObservable(xmlToString(employee));
```