# Pass XML to PHP for all versions of IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml

So I'm passing XML to a PHP file. Things work great in non-IE browsers, and things work great in IE8 and IE11, but not in 9 and 10.

The culprit, I'm betting, is that first "if" condition in the stringIt function below. What I don't know is *why* exactly it works for 8 and 11 but not 9 and 10, and more importantly, ***what should I be doing*** instead to deal with all four versions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function stringIt($xml) {
    var doc = $xml[0],
        string;
    if(window.ActiveXObject) { alert('activeX'); string = doc.xml; }
    else { string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc); }
    return string;
}
```

**EDIT :**
Here's the solution I ended up using. Thanks again for that link tjb.

```
function stringIt($xml) {
    var doc = $xml[0],
        string;
    if(window.ActiveXObject) { alert('activeX'); string = doc.xml; }
    else { string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc); }
    if(string == null) {string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc);}
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try some variation of this:

```
$('<div>').append($xml).html();
```

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885505/762844)

It does mess up casing, though, so `<MyNode ...>` apparently becomes `<mynode>`.

Comment: Thanks tjb. After reading several posts related to the one you linked, I ended up just testing the string after the first if/else in stringIt and if it's null then serialize. Appears to work for all 4 versions.