# How to find and replace xml node value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need help in finding and replacing a value in xml node using JQuery, please suggest, below is my scenario,

```
var metaData ='<Control Type="Table" ID="4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730"></Control>
        <Control Type="TextBox"  ID="7a499af6-16c1-4fe8-9ea0-fe02e7eef886"></Control>';
```

in the above xml structure I want to search for ID="4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730" and replace it with ID="91e3cbe6-8168-40be-bf26-ccdd6acb1e17" in JQuery. Please suggest.

Below is what I tried,

```
var oldID = "4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730";
var newID = "91e3cbe6-8168-40be-bf26-ccdd6acb1e17";
metaData.replace(oldID, newID);
```

the above code was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have just string in `xml` variable, use JS [`.replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257713/how-to-find-and-replace-xml-node-value-in-jquery)

```
xml.replace('4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730', '91e3cbe6-8168-40be-bf26-ccdd6acb1e17');
```

```js
var xml = '<Control Type="Table" ID="4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730"></Control><Control Type="TextBox"  ID="7a499af6-16c1-4fe8-9ea0-fe02e7eef886"></Control>';

var result = xml.replace('4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730', '91e3cbe6-8168-40be-bf26-ccdd6acb1e17');
$("#from").text(xml);
$("#result").text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Before:</b><br/>
<div id='from'></div><br/>
<b>After:</b><br/>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: @Abhinay Well, it's working fine for me. Check updated answer

Comment: let me try again with the approach you suggested.

Comment: @Abhinay don't forget that `.replace` does not modify origin array

Comment: thank you so much, I was expecting the origin array will be modified, after your comment I tried now it is working below is the updated code for replace,    metaData = metaData.replace(oldID, newID);

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do a string replace.

```js
var xml = '<Control Type="Table" ID="4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730"></Control><Control Type="TextBox"  ID="7a499af6-16c1-4fe8-9ea0-fe02e7eef886"></Control>';

var doc = $.parseXML('<root>' + xml + '</root>');
var $root = $(doc);
$root.find('[ID="4900a2a9-47d7-4d3b-9a35-fdd32b185730"]').attr('ID', 'x');
var newxml = xmlToString(doc);
$('#result').text(newxml.substring(6, newxml.length - 7))


//borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery
function xmlToString(xmlData) {

    var xmlString;
    //IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else {
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }
    return xmlString;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```